# MySQL 8.0.18: Key Efficiency 0.0%

Tags: performance, caching, indexing

I have a weird problem. I migrated from MySQL 5.7.x to 8.0.x - recently upgraded to 8.0.18.
Prior to this the key efficiency was generally sitting at 90%+
Now it sits at 0.0%. Despite this, performance seems absolutely fine (I can't tell the difference between before and after) so I gave this low priority and just now am getting around to it.
I am at a bit of a loss with how to resolve it.

The server has 16 CPUs/16 Cores, 64GB of RAM, 1TB of Raid5 SSD + 4TB of SAS on spindle disks. Almost all activity is on data stored on SSD...the spindle disks are where 'old' data goes mostly to die of old age.
Most of the activity is triggers and stored procedures. The system is fed data and this in turn is processed via triggers and routines and then read via API calls from external systems. It doesn't power a CRM of web-site etc.

[MySQL Workbench "Server Status" view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UqpdB.png)

InnoDB my.cnf:

```
innodb_log_file_size            = 1G
innodb_buffer_pool_size         = 52G
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    = 16
#innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size  = xxM
innodb_log_buffer_size          = 120M
innodb_file_per_table           = 1
innodb_page_size                = 16384
innodb_sort_buffer_size         = 16M
innodb_open_files               = 2400
#innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct      = 90  # Default = 90
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit  = 1
innodb_flush_method             = O_DIRECT
innodb_checksum_algorithm       = crc32
innodb_flush_neighbors          = 0
innodb_lock_wait_timeout        = 180
```

Comment: Additional information request. 
Post on pastebin.com and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;
F) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables; 
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes -
htop OR top  for most active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a Linux/Unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: I sent the data. For information the server is running CentOS 7.    
uname -a: Linux DB 3.10.0-1062.9.1.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Fri Dec 6 15:49:49 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Was your MySQL 5.7 implementation using MyISAM data tables?

Comment: No. 100% InnoDB. There are no MyISAM tables. Not since 2014.

Comment: I just want to re-state that I genuinely think this is a bug and that the key efficiency isn't actually 0.0%. I restored the old 5.7 and let it run and the key efficiency is 99.9%. The my.cnf is identical in both cases:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/aqj54pmygkxzgum/MySQL_5.7_status.jpg?dl=0

Comment: Please post TEXT results from 8.0 and 5.7 instances results of SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE "key_%"; for analysis of why key-efficiency is 0  with MySQL version 8.0 Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

Well, this is unexpected. Problem solved.

The MySQL 5.7 we were using has MyISAM tables inside the MySQL schema. Specifically at some point a prior DBA changed some logging tables from CSV for MyISAM; general_log and slow_log. This was done as some admin operations (dashboard for the SysAdmin) were performed on these tables and MyISAM tables seem to be a fair bit faster for doing this as they can be indexed.
When upgrading to 8.0.18 those tables were re-deployed using the standard storage engine for those tables; CSV - and these are not indexed (and hence two parts of our dashboard being slower on 8.0.18 than on the 5.7...I'd been wondering about that and now I know why).

As such, the current 8.0.18 has no MyISAM anywhere. Key_blocks_used, Key_read_requests, Key_reads, Key_write_requests, Key_writes are all permanently 0 and so the "Key Efficiency" as shows in Workbench is also 0.0%.
I'd say it's either a bug or a feature not properly/fully updated in Workbench.

Comment: All they need to do is change the message from Key Efficiency to MyISAM Key Efficiency to clarify the purpose of the output and none of us would expend our time with the research of 'why' is this 0.0  Congratulations.